# In addvalue event listener on datachange I m getting error

Tags: android, firebase

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.navigation, PID: 2579
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.navigation.camera$2$1.onDataChange(camera.java:222)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6748)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:875)
```

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.navigation.camera$2$1.onDataChange(camera.java:222)**

*Can anyone solve this error*

```
DatabaseReference reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        description_info = findViewById(R.id.description_info);
        planting_time_info = findViewById(R.id.planting_time_info);
        bloom_time_info = findViewById(R.id.bloom_time_info);
        Hardiness_info = findViewById(R.id.Hardiness_info);

        moredetails = findViewById(R.id.moredetails);
        moredetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

String Tea = "Tea";
                String Cotton = "Cotton";

                if (Tea.equals(label1.getText().toString())) {

                    reference = reff.child("CropName").child("Tea");

                }else if (Cotton.equals(label1.getText().toString())){
                    reference = reff.child("CropName").child("Cotton");
                }
reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            String description = dataSnapshot.child("description").getValue().toString().trim();
                            String planting_time = dataSnapshot.child("planting_time").getValue().toString().trim();
                            String bloom_time = dataSnapshot.child("bloom_time").getValue().toString().trim();
                            String hardiness = dataSnapshot.child("hardiness").getValue().toString().trim();
                            description_info.setText(description);
                            planting_time_info.setText(planting_time);
                            bloom_time_info.setText(bloom_time);
                            Hardiness_info.setText(hardiness);
                    }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

       }
        });
```

Comment: This most commonly happens if that value does not exist in your database. I recommend printing out your reference path before calling it, and see where it points. Then check that node in the database to make sure all the data is actually there.

Comment: @VirtiParekh have you checked the answer?

Comment: I chaged the reff.addValueEventListener to reference.addValueEventListener then I m getting different error  .

Comment: @A.S.H where I have to put refrence path ? And I have mentioned this already in my database

Comment: @VirtiParekh is your code entering the if else?

Comment: @PeterHaddad  Ya it is entering sometime and then it is crashing from that activity and go back to home page !

Comment: @VirtiParekh add this code inside the else `reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { //`

Comment: @PeterHaddad  Still not working ! `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.navigation.camera$2.onClick(camera.java:220)`

Comment: @VirtiParekh try this `reff.child("CropName").child("Tea").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override`

Comment: @PeterHaddad  Yes it is working , But I m working with multiple values So how can i do for that instead of .child("Tea") what should I put , Actually i want to retrieve the data, when i m clicking on button it should reply the data of a particular label which is appear in the textview from that label it should retrieve the information!

Comment: Add the ValueEventListener inside both the if else but with different child @VirtiParekh

Comment: @PeterHaddad Okay But I Want to retrieve 20 crops information so if i write like this it is too lengthy isn't it ! for that can you suggest something which is helpful?

Comment: @VirtiParekh create a method that will contain a reference so you can just call the valueeventlistener instead of repeating it

Comment: @PeterHaddad can you please tell where I have to create method and what should I write as a code!!  Please if you can give the little hint of code what type it is or else code for that!  It will be great, Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @VirtiParekh you want to get the data from firebase according to a condition. So just create a method where you retrieve the data and call the method inside each condition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212111/discussion-between-virti-parekh-and-peter-haddad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reff.addValueEventListener(//..)` the reference here `reff` is pointing at the root node of the your database. Since `description` is not a direct child under the root node therefore you got the following error. You should change:

```
reff.addValueEventListener
```

Into:

```
reference.addValueEventListener
```

Comment: You beat me to it, I had just noticed that when you posted it. 